# reference request - dynamic discrete time optimization methods

Tags: reference-request, dynamic-optimization

Next semester I am taking business cycle theory course. I emailed my teacher and he replied that I need firm understanding of dynamic discrete time optimization methods. I am gonna study mainly from Sydsaeter / Hammond Further math. Yet I even need to catch up with static optimization, but I have Winter break.

My question is, could you please recommend me some good sources (net / textbooks) for dynamic discrete time optimization methods? Rather introductory. Thank you

Comment: Google something like "dynamic programming bellman equation lecture notes" and pick whatever you like best and you are good to go. My feeling is that these introductory lectures are more or less the same everywhere.

Comment: [Economic Dynamics by John Stachurski](https://johnstachurski.net/edtc)

Comment: @Dayne you should expand it a bit and post it as an answer that book is excellent- Stachursky writes excellent primers (besides dynamical optimization also his primer on econometric theory is very good)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As suggested by 1muflon1:

I don't really use dynamic discrete optimization (yet) in my work, but I did explore several books once. Here are some suggestions:

1. [Economic Dynamics: Theory and Computation by John Stachurski](https://johnstachurski.net/edtc): It's very easy to fall in love with this guy. He writes casually yet authoritatively. The book covers required real analysis and includes python codes and exercises.
2. If you like the above book do explore https://quantecon.org/lectures/
3. [Recursive Methods in Economic Dynamics](https://www.jstor.org/stable/j.ctvjnrt76) by Stokey, Lucas and Prescott